# Django Templates: How to Pass PK/IDs of Displayed Objects Back to the Views.py file from the Template?

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

I want to create a basic comment and posting system on each user’s page. In the Views.py, I call a queryset of all the posts on a user’s page and call it ‘postset’. Then in the template, I loop through the entire queryset and extract the postcontent, postdate, and also the pk/ID of the post for each post in the postset queryset. Then under each post, I also display the form for entering a comment. My problem is that I want to somehow pass the {{ postset.pk }} variable for the corresponding post that the user is filling in the commentform for to the views.py file so that I can store the inputted comment under the correct post that it belongs to. How can I do this? Specifically, how can I get django to understand that the post that each commentform is located under is the post that the entered comment should be attached to via ForeignKey?

Thanks in advance for any help. I'm having a hard time with this. Really appreciate it.

```
<ul>
{% for postset in postset %}
    <br>{{ postset.postcontent }} {{ postset.postdate }} {{ postset.pk }}  
</br>
<form action="/myapp/{{url_paramforURL}}/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ commentform.commentcontent }} 
    <input type="submit" value="Comment" /> 
    <ul>
{% for comment in postset.postcomment_set.all %}
    <br> {{ comment.comment }} {{comment.postcommentdate }}
 {% endfor %}</ul>
 {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with any data, you can either pass it in the URL, or in the form.

For example, you might design the URL that your comment form posts to so that it includes the postset ID, for example: `/myapp/post/<id>/<postset_id>/add_comment/`. Then it's a simple matter of passing those values in the `{% url %}` tag in the template, and using them in the view.

Alternatively, although I don't like this solution as much, you could simply add a hidden input that contains the postset ID:

```
<input type="hidden" name="postset_id" value="{{ postset.id }}">
```

and get it from `request.POST` in the view.

Comment: Thank you. This is fantastic and exactly what I needed. It makes perfect sense, but I just had one question. If I want to do your second way, how should I call the input value in my views.py? What is the best way to call it in views.py?

Comment: It will be in `request.POST['postset_id']`.

Comment: Got it. Works great now. I really appreciate your help.